# Why do I get a weird result for this sum using Android's Java?

Tags: java, android, double

So I'm doing something very simple. I have two instance variables, newX and newY. These are both doubles initialized to 0.0.

During an update loop I perform this calculation:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
double elapsed = (now - mNextTime)/1000.0; // convert to seconds
Log.i("nx", newX + " + " + elapsed + " = " + (newX + elapsed));
newX = newX + elapsed;
newY  = newY + elapsed;
```

Here are a few iterations of the logging statement, this is what I can't explain:

```
1.3073173811609962E9 + 0.058 = 1.3073173812189963E9
1.3073173812189963E9 + 0.112 = 1.3073173813309963E9
1.3073173813309963E9 + 0.02 = 1.3073173813509963E9
1.3073173813509963E9 + 0.018 = 1.3073173813689961E9
1.3073173813689961E9 + 0.018 = 1.307317381386996E9
1.307317381386996E9 + 0.101 = 1.307317381487996E9
```

Why does 1.307 + 0.112 = 1.307?? I'm very confused.

Comment: Floating point number problems in java?... smashing mag did a article on problems associated with javascript here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/30/10-oddities-and-secrets-about-javascript/ the same problem would apply in java, although I don't think this is your answer. Just wanted to point it out.

Comment: What happens if you do: `double testNewX = newX+elapsed; Log.i( testNewX );`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice the E9. You are looking at very large numbers.

1E9 = 1,000,000,000

so

1.3073173811609962E9 + 0.058 = 1,307,317,381.21899623

Comment: I just realized what I was doing! Thanks for that. mLastTime was initializing to 0, totally screwing me up. Simple mistake, thanks!

Comment: @Matthew perhaps mNextTime == 0?